# 3d plot a simple data set with matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Sorry if my question sounds s..., I am new to matplotlib. I have a simple dataset in pandas dataFrame, looks like this:

```
     TAG_1      TAG_2        testTime
0           5      10, 10         758.2
1           5       16, 4        1738.1
2           5        4, 3         752.2
3           5        5, 3         868.9
4           5        5, 4         742.3
```

Is there a way I can 3D plot such a data with matplotlib? TAG_1 and TAG_2 are just simple tags, their values are not important at all, So practically I would use just index column 2 times as X axis and Y axis and testTime column as Z axis. Could you provide me a sample code? thank you in advance.

This is the type of plot I am looking for.
[image: Sample chart]

**EDIT:**
I have managed to plot the following with @furas answer:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this code

```
data = [ [758.2], [1738.1], [752.2], [868.9], [742.3] ]

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

threedee = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')
threedee.plot(df.index, df.index, df[0])

plt.show()
```

I get

[image]

It uses index as X and Y and column as Z, but I don't know if it is what you expected.

---

You need more data to draw something more.

I add more columns

```
data = [
    [0, 1, 100, 758.2],
    [0, 1, 100, 1738.1],
    [0, 1, 100, 752.2],
    [0, 1, 100, 868.9],
    [0, 1, 100, 742.3],
]

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Y = range(df.shape[0])
X = range(df.shape[1])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

threedee = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')
threedee.plot_wireframe(Y, X, df)

plt.show()
```

and I get

[image]

If I replace `X` with `Y` then I get

[image]

To get first version you can replace `X` with `Y` or transform DataFrame

```
df = df.T
```

Comment: Wel thank you so much for the feedback, it works, but what I need is something similar to the image I posted as a sample, is it even possible to have such a chart with matplotlib?

Comment: you would need more columns with data - with one column you can draw only one line.

Comment: but index values are data, don't they? imagine my data for x-axis is actually 1,2,3,4,5...and the same is true for the y-axis. So I have 3 column now, what then?

Comment: X is 1...5 and Y is 1...5 so you have 25 places - so Z need 25 values - 5 columns with 5 values.

Comment: Now I see your point, let me check maybe I could reshape the data, thank you.

Comment: see my new example in answer.